# rails controller use [column_name]_changed? not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, controller

The `[column_name]_changed?` in the controller is not work, but in the model is ok?

```
original_name = "test1"
new_name = "test2"

@user = User.find(params[:id])
puts"__________#{@user.name}" # "test1"
@user.update_attributes(params[:user])
puts"__________#{@user.name}" # "test2"
@user.name_changed? # return false is't not work
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_attributes):

> **update_attributes(attributes, options = {})**
>
> Updates the attributes of the model from the passed-in hash and saves the record, all wrapped in a transaction.

Note the *saves the record* part. So after your `update_attributes` call succeeds, all the new values have been written to the database and nothing will be left in the *changed* state; hence, all the `x_changed?` methods will return false.

If you want something that is like `update_attributes` but doesn't do the `save`, then you ca use [`assign_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment.html#method-i-assign_attributes) or [`attributes=`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment.html#method-i-attributes-3D) instead:

```
@user.assign_attributes(params[:user])
# or @user.attributes = params[:user]
#...
@user.save # You have to do this by hand
```

The [`update_attributes`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/7edade337e968fb028b2b6abfa579120eb424039/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L208) method is just this:

```
with_transaction_returning_status do
  self.assign_attributes(attributes, options)
  save
end
```

after all.

Comment: I will realize the function, I should do？

Comment: @s6520643: So you want the update and save as different steps? Use `assign_attributes` with a separate `save` as in my updated answer.